# How to generate random values with a 99% probability of values falling into (3, 9) exclusive?

Tags: python

this code is to generate a 2 x 5 array of ints between 3 and 9, inclusive:

```
>>> np.random.randint(3,10, size=(2, 5))
array([[6, 8, 5, 7, 6],
       [9, 4, 8, 4, 9]])
```

this code is to generate a 2 x 5 array of the normal distribution.

```
>>> np.random.randn(2,5)
array([[-1.87600791,  0.01958029, -1.07254967, -1.15393634, -0.43278059],
       [ 0.17111773,  1.45624528, -0.74829039, -0.60530629, -0.07440962]])
```

Any normal distribution is unbounded, is it reasonable to generate a 2 x 5 array of normal distribution between 3 and 9, exclusive under a specific probability, such as 99%.

In another word, is it reasonable to implement a function by which all of the random values generated have a probability of 99% fallen into (3,9) exclusive

Comment: "Standard normal" and "between 0 and 4, inclusive" are contradictory.

Comment: Same with "between 3 and 9". The standard normal distribution is unbounded. Any normal distribution is unbounded.

Comment: Standard normal distribution doesn't have limits.

Comment: @user2357112 I've updated the question, would you please take a loot at it?

Comment: @busybear I've updated the question, would you please take a loot at it?

Comment: You may have missed my edit. Any normal distribution is unbounded. Your question is like asking for the vegan way to kill and eat a cow; it is fundamentally impossible due to an inherent contradiction in the premise.

Comment: @user2357112 version6 is coming, would you please take a loot at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. You just need to find the most adequate parameters for the general normal distribution function: mean value and standard deviation. 
Now, the first one is easy to calculate as it is just midway between 3 and 9, which is 6; the second one unfortunately not so much, as you'll need more advanced mathematical tools or at list a very good GDC calculator, but I think you can find some app online that does just that. Anyway, if you trust me with this I calculated it and it should be approximately 1.165.
All there is left to do is to implement them. Easier done than said, as in the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html#numpy.random.randn) it's written very clearly how to proceed. 
This is the code plus the result outputted:

```
>>> 1.165 * np.random.randn(2, 5) + 6
[[5.24339407 6.7414676  4.13757041 7.58498417 5.68613585] 
[6.73871503 8.09501399 7.57774228 4.41143519 5.69703988]]
```

I hope this answer satisfies your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does GDC means **Graphing Distribution Calculator**?

Comment: You're welcome. GDC actually stands for Graphic Display Calculator.

Comment: @MicheleBastione For more convenient alternative to GDC, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

To add to Michele's answer (which is correct) - you can verify your results as below. Also, I just made this [interactive tool](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nmzxbiedrn) you can use for finding any such interval `(x_low, x_high)` - sigma & mu replaced w/ alpha & beta, as Desmos doesn't support them.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = 1.165 * np.random.randn(50000) + 6

plt.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(X), bins=1000)
plt.axvline(x=3, color='r')
plt.axvline(x=9, color='r')

frac_between_3_and_9 = np.sum((X > 3) & (X < 9)) / X.size
print(frac_between_3_and_9)
# .99008
```

[image]